# Mysql Replication 1 Master 2 Slave

Tags: mysql-5.5

I have a mysql replication active. 1 Master and 2 slave.
The first slave works fine, but the seconds slave lags behind master.
This is the results of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G`:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Queueing master event to the relay log
                  Master_Host: IP ADDRESS
                  Master_User: user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.015204
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 88137432
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.065545
                Relay_Log_Pos: 150
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.015199
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 16802785
              Relay_Log_Space: 514144238
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 36745
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.54 sec)
```

This is the results of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State                                  | Info             |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------+
| 60 | root        | localhost | NULL | Query   |     0 | NULL                                   | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
| 61 | system user |           | NULL | Connect |   155 | Queueing master event to the relay log | NULL             |
| 62 | system user |           | NULL | Connect | 34378 | Reading event from the relay log       | NULL             |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------+------------------+`
```

Some one can help to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Share below details:
1) Both slave has the same hardware?
2) Both slave has same configuration (my.cnf)?
3) Network speed must be same on both the slave, please check this as well.

Also check below
3) If using innodb check innodb_buffer_pool_size on both slave.
4) Check whats running on this particular event to identify of you need to optimise any query.